# Choosing PC for Programming. Fastests C++ app build

Tags: processor, development, video, virtual-machines

I am choosing hardware to build a PC. The ways I want to use it:

Programming C++, Qt, Compiling, deploying

Streaming how I am coding (not games)

Virtualization. Running many instances of VMs or dockers

I am looking for a processor. I do not need to play games at all, but streaming requires at least a nice integrated video chip.

I want the CPU to support the fastest M2 SSD and 32gb of the fastest RAM. The main concern is the CPU choice according to my tasks. Shall I choose AMD with many cores or stay with Intel, which has better single thread performance?

Comment: [AMD vs Intel: Does Threadripper mean it’s time to root for the underdog?](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/here-we-explain-the-basic-differences-between-intel-and-amd-cpus/) as well as others indicate that the AMD does seem to have an advantage of throughput over Intel when it comes to multi-threading and multi-processing due to more cores. This article [Ryzen is for Programmers](http://timothypratley.blogspot.com/2017/03/ryzen-is-for-programmers.html) about a build using AMD has some rough comparisons against an older MacBook Pro that was being replaced.

Comment: You would lack a very important data and it is the budget with which you account. but I can recommend you discard Intel because as you say at the beginning you will not play much. For the type of lavor you want to perform you need more cores and RAM mainly for Streaming and Virtualization, so I recommend a Ryzen processor, RAM Gskill or Corsair and Samsung EVO 960 SSD pro that for me is the best

Comment: You say you don't play games, so why even consider an Intel for which you say has better performance for games?  You need to compare on the merits of what you are actually going to use it for.

Comment: I have closed this question as too broad. Please limit your questions to one component. This allows you to describe your requirements and allows the answers to explain the recommendation. If you would like to see an example of how to ask these types of questions, please check out this [question series](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+user%3A60+college). Disclosure: These are my questions.

Comment: @Cfinley I asked only about the CPU

Comment: Still looking for suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this build:

1. Intel  8th gen i5 8600k
2. G.Skill Ripjaws RAM. These ones can be from 4 to 16GB in each stick, but of course more costly.
3. A motherboard that supports overclocking (z370 PRO4 for example) and has enough RAM slots,
4. GTX 1050
5. Most importantly, your CPU cooler must have high TDP( like the H7)
6. Also, your PSU I would say should be about 600w and rated 80+ Bronze or higher. But this will be a costy build.

These are the main parts. You can then get your own choice of case, monitor, peripherals, and LED's etc.

If you get those parts I mentioned into a custom build, then I think you should be good with any program for at least a few years. However, because you said you don't want to play games, you might consider a less powerful GPU of your choice. In any case, I wouldn't completely go without it, just get a cheaper one.